# Why sqlalchemy(1.3) Model's class field can be hint in Model() by pycharm?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pycharm, type-hinting

The class inherit DeclarativeMeta's object can be inferred and it's construction function has type hints with pycharm.

[image: pycharm type hints]

I can not understand how sqlalchemy (only in 1.3) do this . How can I do this with my meta class?

Thanks a lot.